# spring boot admin logfile showing e.headers['content-range']

Tags: spring-boot-admin

SBA  fetches the logs but I think something wrong with displaying it.

The client returns a json.

But SBA shows: 
Fetching logfile failed.
e.headers['content-range'] is undefined

Comment: the /logfile endpoint is not supposed to return json

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please what does it return?

Comment: the plain file contents from the logfile